# How to migrate the custom objects which has link to dlFileEntry objects

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I'm working on staging the custom objects. So to do that I've to export the custom objects into lar file and import that lar file into the fresh staging instance.

I have Member cutom class, which has a long field points to DLFileEntry object(Like foreign key). So now here when I export the Member object its writing the dlFileEntry object id into the lar file xml files. But when I import this Member object into new instance, then the new instance contains fresh DLFileEntry objects. which mismatches to the object Id contained in the member object. So Is there any way to point to the same DLFileEntry object even in staging instance after importing.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any appropriate solution for this. So I did something like this. Added the DLFileEntry object "uuid" value in my custom Member table. So that Even in staging if it creates new DLFileEntry objects, then also "uuid" will remain same. So we can easily find the DLFileEntry objects from member objects after migration too.